# Is it necessary to run migrations for schema change done in MySqlWorkBench in ruby on rails?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql-workbench

I have a rails application which is having a bunch of tables in its schema.
The database is stored on a different machine. And I can handle all the queries like update/search from MySQLWorkBench

I updated one of the table by adding two columns in it from MySQLWorkBench **not by running any rails command.**

So, is there anything else that I need to do so that my schema.rb is changed or it'll change automatically?

In case I am supposed to run a command to let the changes reflect in schema.rb please guide me at what directory I'll run it and on which machine (My developer desktop or the machine on which database is stored).

Comment: Why would you not add this as a migration? Migrations make it easier to understand how and when the database structure changed as well as keeping all environments in sync. Now to answer your question `rake db:schema:dump` will update the db/schema.rb file to reflect the schema of the database by interrogating the database directly so this should add the columns to your schema file but no this will not automatically happen.

Comment: Ok,thank you very much actually I am a newbie in ruby on rails.Can you guide me on which machine I'll run it.The one on my desktop or the machine where database is deployed.According to me it should be database machine but then how'll changes will reflect back in my developer desktop.

Comment: Also a little more insight in the command will really be helpful.Just looking at the command gives an impression as if it is dumping something.

Comment: you would run this in the root directory of the rails application. It is dumping something it is dumping the database schema as the database see it into the db/schema.rb file so that rails see the database the same way. [Insight into rake db commands in Rails](http://jacopretorius.net/2014/02/all-rails-db-rake-tasks-and-what-they-do.html).

Answer (score 0):

First I think its important to understand what the purpose of active record migrations are. The point of migrations is to ensure that any distribution of the source code of your application will be able to consistently recreate your database structure. It is never a good idea to alter the structure of your database outside of a migration (barring some extreme edge case), its ok to alter the state, but not the structure. The best thing you can do is to reverse whatever changes you made in MySQL Workbench and create a migrations(s) that are representative of those changes.